# Improving Mapping trait

Tags: groovy

I have two traits

```
trait Mapping {
    @Delegate
    Map map = new LinkedHashMap()
}

trait Weight {

    private Closure weight

    int getWeight() {
        weight.delegate = this
        weight.call()
    }

    def weight(Closure c) {
        weight = c
    }
}
```

When I apply them to an object I cannot get weight as a property `object.weight` I need to call `object.getWeight()`. Is there any way to change the traits so `object.weight` works.

Here is a test that I would like to work.

```
def 'test traits'() {
    setup:
    def object = new Object()

    when:
    object = object.withTraits(Mapping, Weight)
    object.key = 'value'
    object.weight { 100 }

    then:
    object.key == 'value'
    object.weight == 100
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your `Mapping` trait to:

```
trait Mapping {
    Map map = [:]

    def propertyMissing(String name) {
        map[name]
    }

    def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
        map[name] = value
    }
}
```